# Showing if Open but also show the ticket number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel sheet that is a ticket tracker.  I currently have a formula that will tell me which is the oldest ticket # by two fields, first if the ticket is open or waiting(Column B) and then uses another column (Column D)  to look at the completed date.  This is currently working using

```
=MIN(IF((Main!B:B="Open")+(Main!B:B="Awaiting"),Main!D:D))
```

but would like to have it show the actual oldest date(which it shows now) along with the ticket number which would be column A

[image]

In Yellow shows the oldest date but also want to display the ticket number beside it

[image: In Yellow shows the oldest date but also want to display the ticket number beside it]

Comment: If you could add a small amount of sample data and the expected output that would be helpful

Comment: Updated with screen shots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved answer to account for multiple entries for the same date:
`=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(1,(MIN(IF((B:B="Open")+(B:B="Awaiting"),D:D))=D:D)*((B:B="Open")+(B:B="Awaiting")),0),)`

Old answer:
If you have Office 365 you could use `=FILTER(A:B,D:D=MIN(IF((B:B="Open")+(B:B="Awaiting"),D:D)))`

Else you could use:
`=INDEX($A:$B,MATCH(MIN(IF(($B:$B="Open")+($B:$B="Awaiting"),$D:$D)),$D:$D,0),COLUMN(A:A))`
Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter` and drag to the right one cell.

Both of these only work for unique date values in column D (thanks to Scott Craner pointing this out)

Comment: Both will return a false positive is the date is also found on a line that does not have `A` or `B`.

Comment: Good catch, didn't think of that

Comment: My edit solves it.